# EventMachine disconnects connected clients when a child process with another EventMachine instance is killed

Tags: ruby, multithreading, fork, eventmachine

The parent process starts an EventMachine server in a separate thread and watches and respawns dead workers in the main thread.

The child process starts another EventMachine server and then exits after five seconds.

The problem is that as the new child is starting up, all the connected clients of the parent process is disconnected.

Is there anything I should do to do this properly?

```
require 'eventmachine'

module EchoServer
  def post_init
    puts "-- someone connected to the echo server!"
  end

  def receive_data data
    send_data ">>>you sent: #{data}"
    close_connection if data =~ /quit/i
  end

  def unbind
    puts "-- someone disconnected from the echo server!"
  end
end

puts "Forking..."

def start_echo_server
  Thread.new {
    puts "Starting Echo server"

    EventMachine.run {
      EventMachine.start_server "127.0.0.1", 8081, EchoServer
    }
  }
end

def spawn_workers
  if @pid = fork
    @started = start_echo_server unless @started
  else
    puts "Child #{$$}: Sleeping for 5 seconds"
    EventMachine.run {
      EventMachine.start_server "127.0.0.1", 8082, EchoServer
      EventMachine.add_timer(5) do
        puts "Child #{$$}: exiting..."
        exit
      end
    }
  end

  @pid
end

spawn_workers

if @pid
  begin
    # check if we have any child process that died
    wpid, status = Process.waitpid2(-1, Process::WNOHANG)
    wpid or (sleep 0.1 && next)
    spawn_workers

  rescue Errno::ECHILD
    break
  end while true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem:

Child copies fathers' memory and code of fork. (obviously)
When your father got connected to some clients and then child is spawned, child copies parents' EM loop as well as all its' connection objects.
When child starts new EM loop, old EM loop copied from father stops and therefore all connection objects call "close_connection". You probably have question why fathers connection object copied in child closes connection between father and its' clients? Reasonable question. Because copied object still holds the same socket as father.

Solution:

BEFORE you call EM.run in the child, call "detach" on all connection objects derived from father in the current newly spawned child. "detach" will detach childs' connection object from the socket (father-client) and prevent child from closing that socket.